# C - Keep getting Segmentation Fault when trying to write to Struct Pointer

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I am currently trying to solve a simple hackerrank problem but in a complex way. I'm attempting to keep all values in a structure. But when I try to write to the structure in the function inputNumbers, as soon as the scanf statement is hit, it returns a segmentation fault. I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct numberStructure {
    int intOne;
    int intTwo;
    float floatOne;
    float floatTwo;
} numberStruct, *numberStruct_p;

void inputNumbers(struct numberStructure *);
void outputNumbers(void);

int main(void) {
    
    inputNumbers(numberStruct_p);
    outputNumbers();
    return(0);
}

void inputNumbers(struct numberStructure *numberStruct_p) {
    printf("\n-----WELCOME TO THE PROGRAM-----\n");
    printf("-----ENTER IN TWO INTEGERS (Space separated)-----\n: ");
    scanf("%d %d", numberStruct_p->intOne, numberStruct_p->intTwo);
    printf("-----ENTER IN TWO FLOATS (Space separated)-----\n: ");
    scanf("%f %f", numberStruct_p->floatOne, numberStruct_p->floatTwo);
}

void outputNumbers(void) {
    printf("\n%d %d", (numberStruct.intOne + numberStruct.intTwo), (numberStruct.intOne - numberStruct.intTwo));
    printf("\n%.1f %.1f", (numberStruct.floatOne + numberStruct.floatTwo), (numberStruct.floatOne - numberStruct.floatTwo));
}
```

Comment: In adition your scanfs have errors, you need to pass pointers to the variables, *i.e.* `&numberStruct_p->intOne`, etc.

Comment: Global variable `numberStruct_p` is being tentatively (and finally) initialized to a null pointer value, so the function call `inputNumbers(numberStruct_p);` is effectively equivalent to `inputNumbers(NULL);`. Perhaps you want `} numberStruct, *numberStruct_p = &numberStruct;`. Or you could call `inputNumbers(&numberStruct);` instead.

Comment: Half of everything called out above would be called out with prejudice if you [compile with warnings and treat them as errors](https://godbolt.org/z/bdzfP38nf).

Comment: Get rid of `numberStruct_p`; use the `numberStruct` directly.

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

- You pass `inputNumbers()` a uninitialized struct pointer in `main()`.
- In `inputNumbers()` the arguments to `scanf()` require pointers to the variables but you just pass them as they are.
- In `outputNumbers()` you attempt to print the members of `numberStruct` which are uninitialized.

Improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct numberStructure { 
       int intOne;
       int intTwo;
       float floatOne;
       float floatTwo;
}; 

void inputNumbers(struct numberStructure *s);
void outputNumbers(struct numberStructure *s);

int main(void) 
{ 
    struct numberStructure *numberStruct_p = malloc(sizeof(struct numberStructure));

    if (numberStruct_p == NULL)
        return -1;
    
    inputNumbers(numberStruct_p);
    outputNumbers(numberStruct_p);

    free(numberStruct_p);

    return 0; 
} 

void inputNumbers(struct numberStructure *s) 
{ 
     printf("\n-----WELCOME TO THE PROGRAM-----\n");
     printf("-----ENTER IN TWO INTEGERS (Space separated)-----\n: ");
     scanf("%d %d", &s->intOne, &s->intTwo);
     printf("-----ENTER IN TWO FLOATS (Space separated)-----\n: "); 
     scanf("%f %f", &s->floatOne, &s->floatTwo);
}

void outputNumbers(struct numberStructure *s)
{ 
     printf("\n%d %d", (s->intOne + s->intTwo), (s->intOne - s->intTwo)); 
     printf("\n%.1f %.1f", (s->floatOne + s->floatTwo), (s->floatOne - s->9floatTwo)); 
}
```

Comment: @Neil - I am just curious, where do you see that `numberStruct_p` is shadowed?  It appears to me that the pointer is created in static space, then allocated memory , then passed as arguments to the two functions, then freed, but I do not see shadowing.

Comment: Apologies, that was not a declaration in `main`. Technically, "You pass inputNumbers() a null pointer in main()," since it is of static storage duration. Even simpler on the heap, `struct numberStruct s`.